# I need a simple Toggle script for Windows app called Defender Control

Tags: cmd, toggle, contextmenu

I am using this app called [Defender Control](https://www.sordum.org/9480/defender-control-v1-4/). It works with command line switches "DefenderControl.exe /D" to disable Windows Defender and "DefenderControl.exe /E" to enable Windows Defender. I tried creating and modifying other toggle scripts but I cannot make one work. I have very little knowledge on scripting. I plan to add it to the right-click context menu to quickly disable Windows Defender without having to launch the app then disable it. Thanks in advance.

```
DefenderControl.exe /D

DefenderControl.exe /E
```

Comment: You really should show your attempts, otherwise this is just an off topic script request.

Comment: Do you want the "toggle status" to survive reboots?

Comment: If it's going to be a big deal creating the script then it's not necessary... otherwise why not :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This writes the status to an alternate data stream (technically it's a file, but bound to the batch file), so the status survives reboots:

```
@echo off
REM get current status:
<"%~f0:status" set /p status=
echo Currently: %status%
if "%status%"=="D" (
   defendercontrol.exe /E
   echo E>"%~f0:status"
) else (
   defendercontrol.exe /D
   echo D>"%~f0:status"
)
```

For the very first run, the status is empty and handled the same, as it were `E` (goes to the `else` branch)

Comment: Perfect Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks again for the script. Everything works fine until I add it to the Context menu, then it won't run. Any thoughts?

Comment: "add it to the context menu"? I don't understand.

Comment: I converted the batch file to an .exe and it works fine. But when I added it to the right click context menu through the registry it doesn't run. I have a few batch files too that I converted to .exe and added to the context menu and they all work.

Comment: `%~f0` references the batch file itself. If you converted it to an EXE, this might be useless. Try to replace `"%~f0:status"` with `"%userprofile%\defendercontrol.status"` (all three of them)

Comment: Thanks for the trouble Stephan. I really appreciate it. It still doesn't work though. Actually there is no problem with the EXE. The only problem is in the Right-click context menu.

Comment: Try and give it the full path to `defendercontrol.exe`

Comment: Still nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

The solution for making the script work from the context menu was to elevate it.

```
@echo off
CLS
ECHO.

:init
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "batchPath=%~0"
for %%k in (%0) do set batchName=%%~nk
set "vbsGetPrivileges=%temp%\OEgetPriv_%batchName%.vbs"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:checkPrivileges
NET FILE 1>NUL 2>NUL
if '%errorlevel%' == '0' ( goto gotPrivileges ) else ( goto getPrivileges )

:getPrivileges
if '%1'=='ELEV' (echo ELEV & shift /1 & goto gotPrivileges)
ECHO.

ECHO Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
ECHO args = "ELEV " >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
ECHO For Each strArg in WScript.Arguments >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
ECHO args = args ^& strArg ^& " "  >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
ECHO Next >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
ECHO UAC.ShellExecute "!batchPath!", args, "", "runas", 1 >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
"%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe" "%vbsGetPrivileges%" %*
exit /B

:gotPrivileges
setlocal & pushd .
cd /d %~dp0
if '%1'=='ELEV' (del "%vbsGetPrivileges%" 1>nul 2>nul  &  shift /1)

REM get current status:
<"%userprofile%\defendercontrol.status" set /p status=
echo Currently: %status%
if "%status%"=="D" (
   defendercontrol.exe /E
   echo E>"%userprofile%\defendercontrol.status"
) else (
   defendercontrol.exe /D
   echo D>"%userprofile%\defendercontrol.status"
)
```